# Counter() returning seemingly random large integers

Tags: python, counter

Please forgive the massive code block, but I simply cannot figure out what is going wrong. From what I understand this should work. The wielding list is randomly assigned equipment and then all matching values are summed up for the total. For some reason though, it returns large almost random numbers. I really need help.

```
import random
from collections import Counter

def getRandomWeightedElement(**data):
    rand = random.randint(1, sum(data.values()))

    for key, value in data.items():
        rand -= value
        if rand <= 0:
            return key

equipment = {
"nothing" : Counter({"physA":0}),
"woodenShield" : Counter({"physD":1,"fireD":3}),

#Physical:

#Bronze Weapons
"bronzeDag" : Counter({"physA":12}),
"bronzeSword" : Counter({"physA":23,"physD":2}),
"bronzeBAxe" : Counter({"physA":23}),
"bronze2HSword" : Counter({"physA":26}),
"bronzeMace" : Counter({"physA":26}),
"bronzeWarHammer" : Counter({"physA":26}),

#Iron Weapons
"ironDag" : Counter({"physA":15}),
"ironSword" : Counter({"physA":27,"physD":3}),
"ironBAxe" : Counter({"physA":27}),
"iron2HSword" : Counter({"physA":31}),
"ironMace" : Counter({"physA":31}),
"ironWarHammer" : Counter({"physA":31}),

#Bronze Armor
"bronzeShield" : Counter({"physD":10,"rangD":15,"magD":5}),
"bronzeMedHelm" : Counter({"physD":2,"rangD":4,"magD":1}),
"bronzeFullHelm" : Counter({"physD":4,"rangD":6,"magD":2}),
"bronzeChainbody" : Counter({"physD":6,"rangD":9,"magD":3}),
"bronzePlatebody" : Counter({"physD":7,"rangD":12,"magD":3}),
"bronzeChainlegs" : Counter({"physD":4,"rangD":6,"magD":2}),
"bronzePlatelegs" : Counter({"physD":5,"rangD":8,"magD":2}),
"bronzeBoots" : Counter({"physD":2,"rangD":3,"magD":1}),

#Iron Armor
"ironShield" : Counter({"physD":12,"rangD":18,"magD":6}),
"ironMedHelm" : Counter({"physD":3,"rangD":5,"magD":1}),
"ironFullHelm" : Counter({"physD":4,"rangD":8,"magD":2}),
"ironChainbody" : Counter({"physD":7,"rangD":11,"magD":3}),
"ironPlatebody" : Counter({"physD":9,"rangD":14,"magD":4}),
"ironChainlegs" : Counter({"physD":4,"rangD":8,"magD":2}),
"ironPlatelegs" : Counter({"physD":6,"rangD":9,"magD":3}),
"ironBoots" : Counter({"physD":2,"rangD":4,"magD":1}),

"pineSBow" : Counter({"rangA":22}),
"bronzeNecklace" : Counter({"physD":1}),
"bronzeRing" : Counter({"rangA":0}),
"silverRing" : Counter({"rangA":0})
}

def goblinGen():
    "Generates a Goblin, ready to fight"

    mainH = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"bronzeDag":40,"pineSBow":25,"bronzeSword":15,"bronzeBAxe":10,"ironSword":10})
    offH = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":50,"woodenShield":40,"bronzeShield":10})
    head = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":80,"bronzeMedHelm":15,"ironMedHelm":5})
    neck = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":90,"bronzeNecklace":10})
    chest = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":60,"bronzeChainbody":40})
    legs = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":75,"bronzeChainlegs":20,"ironChainlegs":5})
    gloves = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":95,"leatherGloves":5})
    boots = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":95,"bronzeBoots":5})
    ring1 = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":95,"bronzeRing":5})
    ring2 = getRandomWeightedElement(**{"nothing":95,"silverRing":5})

    wielding = [mainH,offH,head,neck,chest,legs,gloves,boots,ring1,ring2]
    print("\n",wielding,"\n")

    total = equipment["nothing"]

    for item in wielding:
       total += equipment[item]

    print("Physical Attack:",total["physA"],"Physical Defence:",total["physD"])
    print("Ranged Attack:", total["rangA"],"Ranged Defence:", total["rangD"])
    print("Magic Attack:",total["magA"],"Magic Defence:",total["magD"])
    print("Fire Attack Damage",total["fireAD"],"Fire Defence Protection",total["fireDP"])
    print("Poison Attack Chance",total["poisAC"],"Poison Defence Chance",total["poisDC"])
    print("Prayer Offence Bonus",total["prayOB"],"Prayer Defence Bonus",total["prayDB"])

goblinGen()
```

Comment: Why are you using `Counter()`s? Looks like those should just be regular dicts...

Comment: Oh, I see the bug now. You're mutating `equipment['nothing']`... Let me just...

Comment: Can you please tell what you expect and what you get, and it's true that this is huge code block, i bet you can remove most of it and show problem that occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the basic problem was you were mutating the `nothing` Counter, so when you generate several li'l gobbos, the results accumulated. That was fixed by instantiating a new total counter for the total tallying.

I fixed a couple other things too:

- The equipment information is no longer all `Counter`s, as that's unnecessary.
- You don't need to use `**` dictionary unpacking syntax in `getRandomWeightedElement`.
- The goblin's chosen equipment is now stored in a dict, so you can actually see which slot is which at a glance. (`pprint.pprint` is used for nice printing.)

---

```
import random
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

def getRandomWeightedElement(data):
    rand = random.randint(1, sum(data.values()))

    for key, value in data.items():
        rand -= value
        if rand <= 0:
            return key


equipment = {
    "nothing": {"physA": 0},
    "woodenShield": {"physD": 1, "fireD": 3},

    # Physical:

    # Bronze Weapons
    "bronzeDag": {"physA": 12},
    "bronzeSword": {"physA": 23, "physD": 2},
    "bronzeBAxe": {"physA": 23},
    "bronze2HSword": {"physA": 26},
    "bronzeMace": {"physA": 26},
    "bronzeWarHammer": {"physA": 26},

    # Iron Weapons
    "ironDag": {"physA": 15},
    "ironSword": {"physA": 27, "physD": 3},
    "ironBAxe": {"physA": 27},
    "iron2HSword": {"physA": 31},
    "ironMace": {"physA": 31},
    "ironWarHammer": {"physA": 31},

    # Bronze Armor
    "bronzeShield": {"physD": 10, "rangD": 15, "magD": 5},
    "bronzeMedHelm": {"physD": 2, "rangD": 4, "magD": 1},
    "bronzeFullHelm": {"physD": 4, "rangD": 6, "magD": 2},
    "bronzeChainbody": {"physD": 6, "rangD": 9, "magD": 3},
    "bronzePlatebody": {"physD": 7, "rangD": 12, "magD": 3},
    "bronzeChainlegs": {"physD": 4, "rangD": 6, "magD": 2},
    "bronzePlatelegs": {"physD": 5, "rangD": 8, "magD": 2},
    "bronzeBoots": {"physD": 2, "rangD": 3, "magD": 1},

    # Iron Armor
    "ironShield": {"physD": 12, "rangD": 18, "magD": 6},
    "ironMedHelm": {"physD": 3, "rangD": 5, "magD": 1},
    "ironFullHelm": {"physD": 4, "rangD": 8, "magD": 2},
    "ironChainbody": {"physD": 7, "rangD": 11, "magD": 3},
    "ironPlatebody": {"physD": 9, "rangD": 14, "magD": 4},
    "ironChainlegs": {"physD": 4, "rangD": 8, "magD": 2},
    "ironPlatelegs": {"physD": 6, "rangD": 9, "magD": 3},
    "ironBoots": {"physD": 2, "rangD": 4, "magD": 1},

    "pineSBow": {"rangA": 22},
    "bronzeNecklace": {"physD": 1},
    "bronzeRing": {"rangA": 0},
    "silverRing": {"rangA": 0},
}


def goblinGen():
    "Generates a Goblin, ready to fight"

    wielding = {
        'mainH': getRandomWeightedElement({"bronzeDag": 40, "pineSBow": 25, "bronzeSword": 15, "bronzeBAxe": 10, "ironSword": 10}),
        'offH': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 50, "woodenShield": 40, "bronzeShield": 10}),
        'head': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 80, "bronzeMedHelm": 15, "ironMedHelm": 5}),
        'neck': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 90, "bronzeNecklace": 10}),
        'chest': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 60, "bronzeChainbody": 40}),
        'legs': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 75, "bronzeChainlegs": 20, "ironChainlegs": 5}),
        'gloves': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 95, "leatherGloves": 5}),
        'boots': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 95, "bronzeBoots": 5}),
        'ring1': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 95, "bronzeRing": 5}),
        'ring2': getRandomWeightedElement({"nothing": 95, "silverRing": 5}),
    }
    pprint(wielding)

    total = Counter()
    for item in wielding.values():
        total += equipment[item]

    print("Physical Attack:", total["physA"], "Physical Defence:", total["physD"])
    print("Ranged Attack:", total["rangA"], "Ranged Defence:", total["rangD"])
    print("Magic Attack:", total["magA"], "Magic Defence:", total["magD"])
    print("Fire Attack Damage", total["fireAD"], "Fire Defence Protection", total["fireDP"])
    print("Poison Attack Chance", total["poisAC"], "Poison Defence Chance", total["poisDC"])
    print("Prayer Offence Bonus", total["prayOB"], "Prayer Defence Bonus", total["prayDB"])


goblinGen()
```

Example output:

```
{'boots': 'nothing',
 'chest': 'nothing',
 'gloves': 'nothing',
 'head': 'nothing',
 'legs': 'bronzeChainlegs',
 'mainH': 'bronzeBAxe',
 'neck': 'nothing',
 'offH': 'woodenShield',
 'ring1': 'nothing',
 'ring2': 'nothing'}
Physical Attack: 23 Physical Defence: 5
Ranged Attack: 0 Ranged Defence: 6
Magic Attack: 0 Magic Defence: 2
Fire Attack Damage 0 Fire Defence Protection 0
Poison Attack Chance 0 Poison Defence Chance 0
Prayer Offence Bonus 0 Prayer Defence Bonus 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll use all you have showed me and thank you again for helping me learn more